# Python converting integer to hours

Tags: python, django, math, django-views, python-module

I have some math calculation and as result I have some minutes as integer. Now I need help to convert this integer to this format `hh:mm:ss` Trying to do it with datetime but without success.

```
NUM = 594.15
```

Expected output of conversion:

```
9:54:09
```

Comment: ummm thats not an integer ...

Comment: What does this represent? 594.15 hours or 594 hours and 15 mins

Comment: What is the comma meant to mean here? In Python, you defined a tuple of two integers. What do the numbers mean in terms of minutes?

Comment: @jbat100 it is 594.15 minutes and I need hous:minutes:seconds

Comment: comma is typo I just change it to regular decimal number

Comment: @Goran you'd beter add expected output, or your question will probably  be put on hold as unclear one.

Comment: @alko Thanks alko feel free to edit question if you think it's needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import datetime
print datetime.timedelta(minutes=594.15)
```

should do what you want i think

Comment: This doesn't make it a datetime.. but the question doesn't yet make sense.

Comment: he said he just needs to convert it to `hh:mm:ss` ... it does that .. im not sure what the ,15 is all about

Comment: Nope, that's the problem exactly.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks Joran timedelta do the job. Comma is a typo 594.15 minutes